# Uncaught ReferenceError: customerType is not defined (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am getting the following error when clicking on the radiobutton that triggers the change_type function:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: customerType is not defined

I am using the following code:

```
var date_selected = false;
var selected_year = false;
var current_customer = false;
var current_type = false;
var previous_value = 0;

var temp = <?php print_r($json); ?>;
var part = temp['Particulier'];
//console.log(part);
var type = part['Weekend'];
//console.log(type);
var yearArray = type['2016'];
//console.log(yearArray);

var dateSelect = document.getElementsByClassName('dateSelect');
var yearLabel = $("label[for='year']");
var year = document.getElementById('year');
var month = document.getElementById('month');
var date = document.getElementById('date');

$(dateSelect).hide();
yearLabel.hide();

function change_customer(value) {
    current_customer = value;

    var customerType = temp[value];
    console.log(customerType);
}

function change_type(value) {
    $(dateSelect).show();
    yearLabel.show();
    current_type = value;
    if(previous_value == 0) {
        $(dateSelect).show();
    }

    if(current_type == 'Weekend') {
        year.selectedIndex = 0;
        month.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        date.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if(current_type == 'Midweek') {
        year.selectedIndex = 0;
        month.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        date.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if(current_type == 'Week') {
        year.selectedIndex = 0;
        month.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        date.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    previous_value = value;

    var dateType = customerType[value];
    console.log(dateType);
}
```

If any other information is required please ask, new to this, as well as jQuery.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have declared customerType variable in change_customer function as private variable and you accessing it in other function

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp this might be useful

Comment: W3Schools is never useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you declare the `customerType` array inside the `change_customer()` function, so it is out of scope of the `change_type()` function. You need to declare it within scope of both of them. Try this:

```
var customerType = []; // declare empty to prevent unexpected 'access by index' errors

function change_customer(value) {
    customerType = temp[value]; // remove the 'var'
}

function change_type(value) {
    var dateType = customerType[value]; // is now in scope
}
```

Note that I only included the relevant code in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `customerType` in function `change_customer`, so it is not accessible outside of that function. To make the `customerType` accessible in all the functions, you'll need to make it global.

```
var customerType = []; // In global scope(outside of all functions)
.
.
.
function change_customer(value) {
    current_customer = value;

    customerType = temp[value];
    console.log(customerType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_customer(value) {
    current_customer = value;

    var customerType = temp[value];
    console.log(customerType);
}

function change_type(value) {
    $(dateSelect).show();
    yearLabel.show();
    current_type = value;
    if(previous_value == 0) {
        $(dateSelect).show();
    }

    if(current_type == 'Weekend') {
        year.selectedIndex = 0;
        month.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        date.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if(current_type == 'Midweek') {
        year.selectedIndex = 0;
        month.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        date.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if(current_type == 'Week') {
        year.selectedIndex = 0;
        month.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        date.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    previous_value = value;

    var dateType = customerType[value];
    console.log(dateType);
}
```

> In the above code you have initialized `customerType`  variable inside
>   the `change_customer` function and you are trying to access it in   `change_type` function which is beyond its scope
>   scope so your choice is make it globalized as u did some variables.

Answer (score 0):

well you do not call your `change_customer` function anywhere inside the `change_type` function. Therefore `customerType` will never be instatiated.

try adding your function like this:

```
function change_customer(value) {
    var current_customer = value;

    var customerType = temp[value];
    return customerType;
}

function change_type(value) {
    var customerType = change_customer(value);
    $(dateSelect).show();
    yearLabel.show();
    ......
}
```

although, where is your `temp` array with the key `value`?

Answer (score 0):

Your change_type function is trying to use customerType when it has not been declared. You need to declare customerType along with the rest of your global variables, not within the scope of the change_customer function :)